# Iteration on Backbone collection by underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm try to iterate on a Backbone collection but the console inside each function print ever undefined.

```
     toPost: function(id){


        var myattori = new Attori();
            myattori.fetch({
            success: function(r) {
               console.log(r);// collection correctly filled
                _.each(r, function(model) {


                   console.log(model);//undefined

                }, this);
            }
        });



    },
```

Comment: i think you should do _.each(r.models, function(model){ ......

Comment: Could you post one example of `console.log(r);`

Comment: Ok you're right! @DhirajBodicherla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: as @mu is too short suggested you can use the built-in method collection.each too.

```
r.each(function(model){ ... })
```

I believe you can do r.models. Hope this helps

```
toPost: function(id){


        var myattori = new Attori();
            myattori.fetch({
            success: function(r) {
               console.log(r);// collection correctly filled
                _.each(r.models, function(model) {


                   console.log(model);//undefined

                }, this);
            }
        });



    },
```